# Does anyone recognise this icon?

Tags: google-chrome, icons

Can anyone tell me what this icon on Chrome in my taskbar is?

It has only appeared today, I think chrome updated this morning but I can't be 100% sure.

[image]

It seems as if it's being triggered when I login somewhere (Facebook, Salesforce, etc...) using an incognito tab.

Comment: check your version of Chrome and check what is current official build to see weather it is updateed or not?

Comment: Gotta love Sublime Text ♥

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That is the icon that's associated with your Google Chrome profile.
[image: Chrome - People]

You'll see the icon in the taskbar as well.
[image: taskbar icons]

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is an update of Google chrome. It is the icon to create Google chrome account, which help to sync your bookmarks, history, etc., across all your devices.

Comment: You forgot the "send all your data for analytics and advertising" part.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Took me two minutes to understood the joke :P

Comment: @SantaClaus if only it was a joke. :(